raspberry Piのスイッチ入力の実行回数に関して 1回のスイッチ入力に対して　複数回の出力が確認されることがある。（sleep時間による）
raspberry　pythonの初心者ですが　スイッチ入力に対して　所定の動作をするプログラムを組みましたが
キー割り込み　callback関数後の　別処理用のtime.sleep関数の値によって　２回割り込み処理が発行されることがあります。割り込み処理を１回にしたいのですが解決策　ヒントなどございましたらお教えください。
動作させたハードウェア ：raspberry-pi zero2W
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 11(bullseye)
ソースコードは下記になります。（不要部分を外して簡略化してあります）
また　このソースコードでも実行しており　その結果を下に記してあります。
#!usr/bin/env.python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import board
import digitalio
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
 
CountupSw = 20 # PLUS1 Count GPIO20 Pin=38
global x
   
def switch_PLUS(pin):

    global x
    x = x + 1
    print("START switch_PLUS=",time.time())

    W3_sleep= 5
    time.sleep(W3_sleep)  # (BOUNCETIME=5000,sleep2 OK  3 NG)(BOUNCETIME=7000 SLEEP(4)OK 5 NG)
    print("WORK3.SLEEP=",W3_sleep,"S")
    print("WORK_3=",x,"回")
    print("WORK3_Time=",time.time())
    print()

b_time=2000

GPIO.setup(CountupSw, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

GPIO.add_event_detect(CountupSw,GPIO.FALLING,callback = switch_PLUS, bouncetime = b_time)
print("bouncetime=",b_time)
x=0

def main():

    try:        

            while True:
                time.sleep(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("例外'KeyboardInterrupt'を捕捉")
     
        print("処理を終了します")
     
        GPIO.cleanup()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    
    

W3_sleep=5　（スイッチ入力後 time.sleep(5)) での実行結果は （２回出力動作後終了）
bouncetime= 2000
START switch_PLUS= 1713410428.0825374
WORK3.SLEEP= 5 S
WORK_3= 1 回
WORK3_Time= 1713410433.0877821

START switch_PLUS= 1713410433.08794
WORK3.SLEEP= 5 S
WORK_3= 2 回
WORK3_Time= 1713410438.0931332

例外'KeyboardInterrupt'を捕捉
処理を終了します    

W3_sleep=1 （スイッチ入力後 time.sleep(1)) での実行結果は （１回出力動作後終了）
bouncetime= 2000
START switch_PLUS= 1713411625.3765001
WORK3.SLEEP= 1 S
WORK_3= 1 回
WORK3_Time= 1713411626.3778965

例外'KeyboardInterrupt'を捕捉
処理を終了します

となってしまいます。
また　bouncetimeも関わっている様です。（チャッターの問題ではなく）

スイッチには、チャタリングと言う現象が発生します。
なので、スイッチ入力の割り込みを使用するってのはダメですね

問題点が 2箇所ほどあるようです

パラメーターbouncetime= の指定時間が長過ぎる
コールバック処理 switch_PLUS(pin) に負荷を(時間を)掛けている

(wikipedia.org) チャタリング より

チャタリング (英: chattering、Contact bounce、chatter) とは、可動接点などが接触状態になる際に、微細な非常に速い機械的振動を起こす現象のことである。

簡単に示すとこんな感じ

スイッチを押す際

press + ( release, press ) * n回


離す際

release + ( press, release ) * n回



デバウンスについて
参考: (digikey.jp) ソフトウェアによるデバウンスが適切でない場合のスイッチおよびリレーへのハードウェアデバウンスの実装方法
(単に検索でヒットしたページだけど, 図など参考になるはず)

ソフトウェア開発者がスイッチの専門知識を持っていないという問題は、スイッチのバウンスに関する文献がしばしば矛盾していたり、混乱を招いたりする事実によってさらに悪化します。たとえば一般的には、スイッチのアクティブ化または非アクティブ化後、スイッチのバウンスは1ミリ秒（ms）で停止すると思われています。しかし、有名な組み込みシステムの専門家であるジャック・ガンスレ氏は、様々なタイプのスイッチを用いて、各スイッチを300回作動させ、接点の開閉の際のバウンスの最小値と最大値を記録するという実験テストを行いました。その時の平均バウンス時間は1.6ms、最大バウンス時間は6.2msと報告されています。産業用および軍事用の「ベストプラクティス」の中には、最初の作動から20ms待ってから、スイッチのバウンスが止まった見なすことを推奨するものもあれば、何らかのアクションを開始する前に最後に検出されたバウンスから20ms待つことを推奨するものもあります。

ソフトウェアのデバウンスでは 20ms 程度ということだが,
(別サイトによると) 材質の違いもあり数十ms の場合もあるそうなので 100ms くらいあれば十分でしょう。
(RPi.GPIOモジュールのサンプルコードでは bouncetime=200 の指定もあるが)
このバウンス時間は, 無駄に長いと かえってトラブルを招きます
例えばスイッチを離す際のチャタリングによって「押された」と判定される可能性があるため
(たまたまそのタイミングでバウンス時間が切れた場合)
コールバックについて
Threaded callbacks (スレッド化されたコールバック) に記載された内容からすると
メインと同時に実行できるものの, コールバック用のスレッドはひとつだけなのでコールバックが複数あっても同時に動くことはない, とのこと
コールバックに数秒の時間を掛けると, その間は RPi.GPIO moduleはコールバックを呼び出すことはできず
(実装にもよるが) スイッチの割り込みだけ保持してるのではないかと思われ, 多分コールバックの終了時に続けて呼び出すことになるのでしょう
RPi.GPIO に限らす, 「コールバック」もしくは「ハンドラー」はたいてい速やかに処理を終わらせないといけないものです。そうしないとトラブルのもとになるから。(処理落ちが発生したり, あらぬタイミングで纏めて処理が走ったり)
より低レベルの OSに近い処理だと, ファイル I/O 含め表示も禁止の場合もあるけれど
Pythonのモジュールであれば, 表示くらいは OKでしょう
けれど, 長い時間(数秒)かかることが予想される処理(例えば何らかのクエリーなど)はコールバックの外部で行うべきです
